# Enabling Folder Actions Within OS X?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, folder-action

There is an element to OS X known as **Folder Actions**, which causes certain actions or events to occur when items are either added or removed from user specific folders.

How can I enable this ?

(I am using OS X 10.6.8, but if the activation differs for OS X 10.7.5 or 10.8.4 this is also welcomed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, bear in mind that **Folder Actions** can be configured through **AppleScript** to perform a huge variety of actions, and that there are some default scripts among which you'll find the *adding / removing* action you mention.

Since **10.6** the **Folder Actions Setup** panel is accessible through any folder's contextual menu:

1. Do <kbd>Control</kbd>+click (or *right click*) on any folder for the *contextual menu* to show.
2. Choose **Folder Actions Setup**. ( If you've got any *eligible* services already, it would be slightly different as you'll have to go to choose **Services** and then **Folder Actions Setup**.)
3. Choose the **add - new item alert** script from the prompt window.
4. Select the *Enable Folder Actions* option in the upper-left side of
   the setup's window.

You'll have, though, to edit the script for it to do something *useful* as, right not, it only displays an alert saying that an new *item* has been added to the folder.

Answer (score 1):

To enable folder actions open your Automator.

[image]

There you can create folder actions pending your needs.

Once you have created it, right click on any folder and in the pop up choose the desired action.

Comment: The actions are predetermined & numerous ?